# Fluent NHibernate Child collection persistence issues

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following mapping classes (only the relevant part copied):

```
public class CardTemplateMapping : ClassMap<CardTemplate>
{
    public CardTemplateMapping()
    {
        Table("cardtemplate");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("id")
            .GeneratedBy.Native();

        HasMany(x => x.CostStructures)
            .KeyColumn("cardtemplate_id")
            .Cascade.All();

    }
}
public class CostStructureMapping : ClassMap<CostStructure>
{
    public CostStructureMapping()
    {
        Table("coststructure");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("id")
            .GeneratedBy.Native();

        References(x => x.CardTemplate)
            .Column("cardtemplate_id");

        HasMany(x => x.CostComponents)
            .KeyColumn("coststructure_id")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

    }
}
public class CostStructureComponentMapping : ClassMap<CostStructureComponent>
{
    public CostStructureComponentMapping()
    {
        Table("CostStructureComponent");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("id")
            .GeneratedBy.Native();

        References(x => x.CostStructure)
            .Column("coststructure_id");

        References(x => x.ResourceType)
            .Column("resourcetype_id");
    }
}
```

Nhibernate loads the relations as I intended. But two parts of the Mapping seem a bit weird (either that or my expectations are weird).

First:

```
 CostStructure structure = new CostStructure() { CardTemplate = template };
 template.CostStructures.Add(structure);
 Session.Save(template);
 Session.Flush();
```

This does not save the new `CostStructure` instance. Why?

Second one: Assuming I have loaded a `CardTemplate` having a `CostStructure` containing three `CostStructureComponent` entities. Now I want to remove one of those `CostStructureComponents` from the `CostStructure`.
I tried the following :

```
costStructure.CostComponents.Remove(component);
component.CostStructure = null;
session.Save(template)
```

Now, I know that explicitly deleting explicitly works, but shouldn't the `DeleteOrphan` part also assert that the component, now without `CostStructure` to reference, is deleted? Instead, NHibernate tries to perform the following update:

```
UPDATE CostStructureComponent 
SET amount = @p0, 
     coststructure_id = @p1, 
     resourcetype_id = @p2
WHERE id = @p3;

@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
@p1 = NULL [Type: Int64 (0)], 
@p2 = 5 [Type: Int64 (0)], 
@p3 = 13 [Type: Int64 (0)]
```

Could it be Equals / GetHashCode have been implemented the wrong way?

Sorry, it's late, been a long day and so forth...If I'm talking gibberish, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are hidden in one setting `.Inverse()`

```
public CardTemplateMapping()
{
    HasMany(x => x.CostStructures)
        .KeyColumn("cardtemplate_id")
        .Cascade.All()
        .Inverse(); // HERE this setting
```

And here:

```
public CostStructureMapping()
{
    ..
    HasMany(x => x.CostComponents)
        .KeyColumn("coststructure_id")
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .Inverse();  // and HERE and everywhere on HasMany()
```

Try to find some articles about this setting, but in general: If mapped as inverse, NHibernate is ready to do much better SQL Statements, because it is working with other end of relation...

Some sources:

[19.5.2. Lists, maps, idbags and sets are the most efficient collections to update](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections-mostefficientupdate) *cite:*

> However, in well-designed NHibernate domain models, we usually see that most collections are in fact `one-to-many` *(comment: HasMany in Fluent)* associations with **`inverse="true"`**. For these associations, the update is handled by the `many-to-one` *(comment: References in Fluent)* end of the association, and so considerations of collection update performance simply do not apply.

[6.2. Mapping a Collection](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping)

> **inverse** *(optional - defaults to false)* mark this collection as the "inverse" end of a bidirectional association

Comment: Thanks, Radim, I will try this when I'm back home.