# Fluent NHibernate bulk data insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need to transfer some data to other db, but when I start this mssql server freeze.
ds2 row count about 250,000. What am I doing wrong?

every time I try same funcion first looks working and after give error on random row. maybe 5, 95 or 280. until error records looks valid.

```
        string inlineSql = "Select * from album";
        DataSet ds2 = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, inlineSql);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Entity.Album.Album album = new Entity.Album.Album();
            album.AlbumName = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AlbumName"].ToString();
            album.WebSite = (Entity.Artist.WebSite)Convert.ToInt16(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["WebSite"]);
            album.Year = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Year"].ToString();

            Entity.Artist.Artist artist = Entity.Artist.Artist.READ.ById(Convert.ToInt32(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ArtistId"]));
            if (artist != null)
            {
                artist.AddAlbum(album);
                album.Save();
            }
        }
```

AddAlbum Method

```
    public virtual void AddAlbum(Album.Album album)
    {
        album.Artist = this;
        AlbumList.Add(album);
    }
```

Save Method

```
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(x);

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Error on `session.SaveOrUpdate(x);`

Error :

> An exception of type 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException'
>   occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: could not insert: [Entity.Album.Album][SQL:
>   INSERT INTO [Album]
>
> (AlbumName, WebSite, Year, ArtistId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); select
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

AlbumMap

> ```
> public class AlbumMap : ClassMap<Album>
> {
>     public AlbumMap()
>     {
>         Id(x => x.AlbumId);
>         Map(x => x.AlbumName);
>         Map(x => x.WebSite).CustomType<short>();
>         Map(x => x.Year);
>         HasMany(x => x.LyricList).Table("Lyric").KeyColumn("AlbumId").Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
>         References(x => x.Artist).Column("ArtistId").ForeignKey("ArtistId").Fetch.Join();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

ArtistMap

```
public class ArtistMap : ClassMap<Artist>
{
    public ArtistMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ArtistId);
        Map(x => x.ArtistName);
        Map(x => x.ArtistURL);
        Map(x => x.ImgName);
        Map(x => x.ImgURL);
        Map(x => x.Alfabet);
        Map(x => x.SeoLink);
        Map(x => x.WebSite).CustomType<short>();
        HasMany(x => x.AlbumList).Table("Album").KeyColumn("ArtistId").Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
    }

}
```

More Exception

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FKA0CE20AA48AC4CAD". The conflict occurred in database "LYRICSWEB",
>   table "dbo.Artist", column 'ArtistId'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Comment: Could you add next lines of that exception, please? exactly there will be intersting info... HINT: what we can see now, seems, like the `albumId` column does not have turned on the identity...

Comment: this is all of the exception. AlbumId Identity specification YES also I am adding ClassMap

Comment: ah I didn't know there is more, I found complete exception adding now.

Comment: So, I found one issue (check my answer). That must be fixed anyway... But maybe we will face other issues.. let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some indications, which should lead to the answer. We can see that the error is:

> Additional information: could not insert: [Entity.Album.Album][SQL: INSERT INTO [Album]
>   (AlbumName, WebSite, Year, ArtistId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

while we are loading artist correct way...

```
Entity.Artist.Artist artist = Entity.Artist.Artist.READ
  .ById(Convert.ToInt32(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ArtistId"]));
```

The issue would be in incorrect collection mapping. The reference from Albumt to Artist seem to be correct:

```
public AlbumMap()
{
    ..
    References(x => x.Artist)
       .Column("ArtistId")
       .ForeignKey("ArtistId")
       .Fetch.Join();
}
```

But the other end of that relation is mapped like this:

```
// wrong
public ArtistMap()
{
    ..
    HasMany(x => x.AlbumList)
       .Table("Album")
       .KeyColumn("AlbumId")         // wrong
       .Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
}
```

Both above relations are **the same**! They are only mapped from different ends *(from collection item perspective and from collection owner perespective)*.

That means that **the mapping column must be the same**, i.e. not `"AlbumId"` but **`"ArtistId"`**

```
// correct
public ArtistMap()
{
    ..
    HasMany(x => x.AlbumList)
       .Table("Album")
       .KeyColumn("ArtistId")         // this is the relation
       .Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
}
```

Because NHibernate loads some artist, and its collection of AlubmList.. it could lead to some unexpected insert statements... fix of that mapping should help...

#### Second thing to mention: `Inverse()`

We are working with `Album` instances... and we are assigning their relation to collection holder - `Artist`. This is good and suggested way how to do that. Good.

But we can profit from NHibernate feature called Inverse() which will reduce few SQL statements... and make all the insert more simple... so extend your Artist mapping like this:

```
// correct
public ArtistMap()
{
    ..
    HasMany(x => x.AlbumList)
       .Table("Album")
       .KeyColumn("ArtistId")  // this is the relation
       .Cascade.All()
       .Not.LazyLoad()
       .Inverse();             // ESSENTIAL improvement of generated SQL
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325810/1679310) for more details

Comment: You were right about ArtistId I fixed that also tried Inverse but non of them solve the error. This information may help, every time I try same funcion first looks working and after give error on random row. maybe 5, 95 or 280. until error records looks valid.

Comment: That kind of information is not helping ;( ... random problems... unpredictable... I can help with a captured issue ... if you know what I mean.. try, please to find more details... and again, the exception stack *(if it is new exception even better maybe to issue new question, only if the exception is totally different)* BUT, if the exception is still the same - try to compare all the values in ArtistId FROM table/db ... if they exist in the TARGET table/db

Comment: I deleted album table to recreate itself with new ArtistId and Inverse fix. It seems now changes be applied. 1000+ row still no error! I think ArtistId fixed it. thank you very much :)

Comment: Great to see that sir! NHibernate is simply amazing tool ;) Enjoy it