# NHibernate <one-to-many>

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

How can I map these two classes?

```
public class LDAVehicle 
{
    public virtual int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ChassisSeries { get; set; }
    public virtual string ChassisNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual List<LDAReading> Readings { get; set; }
}

public class LDAReading 
{
    public virtual int ReadingId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime IncomingDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ReadoutDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Sender { get; set; }

    public virtual LDAVehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

Accually I have this xml:

```
<class name="LDAVehicle" table="Vehicle" schema="dbo" lazy="false">
    <id name="VehicleId">
        <column name="VehicleId" />
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="ChassisSeries" column="ChassisSeries" not-null="false" />
    <property name="ChassisNumber" column="ChassisNumber" not-null="false" />

    <set name="Readings" table="Reading" fetch="join">
        <key foreign-key="VehicleId" />
        <one-to-many class="LDAReading" />
    </set>
</class>

<class name="LDAReading" table="Reading" schema="dbo" lazy="false">
    <id name="ReadingId">
        <column name="ReadingId" />
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="IncomingDate" column="IncomingDate" not-null="true" />
    <property name="ReadoutDate" column="ReadoutDate" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Sender" column="Sender" not-null="false" />
    <many-to-one name="Vehicle" class="LDAVehicle" fetch="select" column="VehicleId" />
</class>
```

But I get an error:

> An association from the table Reading refers to an unmapped class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few improvements I would made to make it running

1) C#

If we map collections, they MUST be represented as interfaces, so NHibernate will be able to inject proxies... own implementation

```
public class LDAVehicle 
{
    public virtual int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ChassisSeries { get; set; }
    public virtual string ChassisNumber { get; set; }

    //public virtual List<LDAReading> Readings { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<LDAReading> Readings { get; set; }
}

public class LDAReading 
{
    public virtual int ReadingId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime IncomingDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ReadoutDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Sender { get; set; }

    public virtual LDAVehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

2) hbm

For mapping collection I would use bag *(until NHibernate 4 is released with native use of System stuff, we would need to use iesi collection ... so `<bag>` is good enough now)*.

Also if propery name and column are same, we do not have to mention column.

Finally, all mappings are strongly LAZY now. This is simply the way which to go

```
<class name="LDAVehicle" table="Vehicle" schema="dbo" lazy="true"> // should be lazy
    <id name="VehicleId" column="VehicleId" generator="native" />  // simple id def

    <property name="ChassisSeries" not-null="false" /> // name is enough
    <property name="ChassisNumber" not-null="false" /> // if column is the same

    // IList and <bag> go work together
    // also profit from lazy loading, 
    //  batch size fetching and inverse mapping
    <bag name="Readings" lazy="true" inverse="true" 
                         batch-size="25" cascade="all-delete-orphan"> 
        <key column="VehicleId" />
        <one-to-many class="LDAReading" />
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="LDAReading" table="Reading" schema="dbo" lazy="true">
    <id name="ReadingId" generator="native" />

    <property name="IncomingDate" not-null="true" />
    <property name="ReadoutDate"  not-null="true" />
    <property name="Sender"       not-null="false" />

    <many-to-one name="Vehicle" class="LDAVehicle" column="VehicleId" />
</class>
```

3) be sure that both mapping are **Emebedded Resources**. If one of these is not found... not embedded... the exception as in the question is thrown... Also, both files should/must have suffix `.hbm.xml`

More reading:

- [inverse mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319489/fluent-nhibernate-child-collection-persistence-issues/21325810#21325810)
- Ayende - [NHibernate is lazy, just live with it](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)
- [batch size fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310)

Comment: I still have this error :( Are mapping are emebeded.
LDAVehicle is in Test.DomainLayer.Entities 
LDAReading is in Test.DomainLayer.Entities too.

In hbm file i use 
namespace="Test.DomainLayer.Entities" assembly="Test.Model"

In nhibernate config:
<mapping assembly="Test.Model"></mapping>

Comment: Are you sure that your mapping files are named xxx.hbm.xml ? the `.hbm.xml` suffix is essential. And also, are you sure that in properties *(select file and click F4)* is `"Embedded Resource"`?

Comment: Resolved! in one file i have uncorrect name, .hbL.xml . Thanks!

Comment: Great to see that;) please, try to follow my suggestion, that will simplify your life with mighty NHibernate ;)